# tHttpClient retry on 5## response

Tags: talend

I'm trying to make my tHttpClient API calls a bit more robust.

Currently my first call to this remote API is to retrieve how many records there are to be retrieved, after that I loop through that amount with a given page size. this easily results in having to call the API 600+ times and once in a while the API throws a 500 - timeout response. How could I improve this subjob to retry that same request with # seconds delay instead of terminating the job?
[image: Current Talend Subjob]

Part of the difficulty is that the second API call uses the 'extract a sub-part of the response' function to split the JSON response into the paginated objects the API returns, with this I have difficulty to add the status code to each row.

If it is possible to get the status code there I might be able to switch the loop from 'for' to 'while' and add in the javaRows to handle error responses.